# Module not found when using variable to require image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am having a problem with react that I really don´t know why is happening.
I am using Accuweather API, and want to show the weather icon. Everything is working fine, I created the following path for the images:

```
var imgUrl = `../../img/WeatherImages/${weatherIcon}.png`
```

I make the console.log and shows the path correctly: ../../img/WeatherImages/2.png

The problem comes when I require the image:

```
<img src={ require(`${imgUrl}`).default }/>
```

Automatically react breaks and shows the following error:

"Error: Cannot find module '../../img/WeatherImages/2.png'"

When refreshing, the message changes:

"Error: Cannot find module '../../img/WeatherImages/.png'"

It seems that is not recognizing the variable.
Do you know what I am doing wrong??

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

It is due to because relative path might be broken during build in cra to web browser.you just put the img folder in public folder and just make the directory into "/img/WeatherImages/yourimage.jpg"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).